# PHP how to save php table result to .PDF file

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, header

What I want to achieve is when the user click on the link and come to this page. There will be a pop-up msg to ask the user to save this .php file to .pdf. Basically, I want to save this result to a .pdf file from a .php with the result from mysql database.

Comment: there are many html to pdf scripts available, go try one. I recommend: TCPDF

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert HTML + CSS to PDF with PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/391005/convert-html-css-to-pdf-with-php)

Comment: you can use html2pdf. http://html2pdf.fr/en/default It will easily convert html code into pdf. Here's a tutorial http://goo.gl/R2jdW

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to save the HTML output as PDF, these two resources are easy to use and setup:

http://www.tcpdf.org/

http://pdfcrowd.com/hub/2011/04/18/convert-html-to-pdf-in-php.html